# ASP.Net MVC 4 How to create a simplemembership account without a password

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, user-registration

I am building an MVC4 app in which users will be registered by a site admin.  The site admin will enter everything but the password of course.  I then generate a token and send via email for them to set their password.  However, I don't see a way to create a user without a password.  I can either randomly generate one or assign one in the code.  What is the best way to handle not having a password at account creation?

EDIT:
I used Membership.GeneratePassword for generate the password when I created the account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a random password and allow them to change once the account is confirmed. Solves a number of problems.

Comment: For a random password I use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` :)

Comment: Do not user NewGuid() for password generation, they are predictable. Instead use a secure random number generator like `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: In my case, users have the option to login with a digital certificate. When the admin register a user to use a certificate, the system generate a very strong password and the user will never knows unless the admin changes its profile to enable login with sername/password